# I have some queries in MediaElement.js

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova, mediaelement.js

Was developing a phonegap based mobile app for Android and IOs.

I have some queries in it.

--Whether adaptive bit stream work using MediaElement.js in web view based apps.

--Is it possible to add vast tags in it.

If I use mediaElement.js in my html5 based app will I be able to stream the video in adaptive bit rate and want to play the vast ad tags.